# regex on large byte array converted to string bringing back wrong results

Tags: c#, regex

I have converted a very large byte array to a string in order to search it using a regex. The pattern i am seeking is giving me trouble. in  the byte form i would be looking for a hex representation like this:3f3f3f41351b543f. I say 'like' this because the discerning factor is the recurrence of 3f within the string. The pattern i have is ([3f]){2,8} but this is  bringing back strings with three to eight f's in them. my question is how can i search for substrings 16 charachters long in a larger string which contain  recurrences of the sequence 3f. I feel embarrassed to ask this but I have certainly tried to solve the issue myself as well as examining some forums online.

Update: with thanks to smead for his input and respect to Wiktor Stribiżew and Chris Britt for not producing a clear enough question( first post for me)  I have tried smeads answer and it works.Thank you all very much.

Further update. Things have developed a little here and i am still trying to fathom the regex world. I am going to be much more concise because I still need help and I am grateful if I get any.
I am programming in c# and am searching a minidump. I know there are alternative more effective ways of searching  minidumps , nevertheless this is the mission:

I have one very very long string which I made by reading in the bytes of a file and then converting them using a Stringbuilder so that I can parse them with a regex. the string looks like this:
00000028353B0200000000B8ECC70400000000000000006C21C8040000000028353B0200000000AD35C804080000003F3F093F3F3F5F2C000000000836C3040100000038343B0200000000AD35C804080000003E3E083E3E3E5E2C00000000AD35B804080000003E3E083E3E3E5E2C00000000AC35C804080000003F3F093F3F3F5F2C00000000AD35B804080000003F3F093F3F3F5F2C000000006CF4C7040500000058C6380204363B0288C6380260683B02C4C638020000000018E9C704010000003100000000000000282FC804D84D360200000000000000000000000000

...but is far far longer than that. Now what I want to do is to search the entire string and return the match to a sequence that looks **like** this:

3F3F093F3F3F5F2C

the information i have is that within the sixteen charachters in the substring will be contained the sequence "3F" >3<8 times but not neccessarily consequently. the regex I am currently using for this is (3f){2,8} . On short sequences like preceeding example above this seems to work. But it fails entirely bringing back allsorts of stuff on the larger string.

So finally my question is how can i search this very long string for all 16 charachter substrings with a number of included but not neccessarily consecutive "3f" sequences ? I hope this is clearer. any help would be much obliged.

Comment: That is rather unclear. `(?:3f){8}`?

Comment: Please take a look at [ask] and [mcve] for information on how best to revise and format your question so that it is clear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: @ WiktorStribiżew and @ChrisBritt I have tried my best to clarify for you both the question I have and would still appreciate anything you have to offer on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood correctly you want to select sub-strings of length 16 starting with 3F and then if substring contains 3F more than 3 times but less than 8 time then substring qualifies for you. have a look at the below code.

```
void Main()
{
    string data ="000000283533F5F2C00000000AD35B8040800000B0200000000B8ECC70400000000000000006C21C8040000000028353B0200000000AD35C804080000003F3F093F3F3F5F2C000000000836C3";
    string pat = "(3F.{14})";
    string pat2 = "3F";
    var rg = new Regex(pat);

    var data2 = rg.Matches(data);
    foreach (Match  mat in  data2 )
    {
        string potentialMatch =  mat.Value; 

        int count = Regex.Matches(potentialMatch, pat2).Count;
        if (count>3 && count<8)
        {
         Console.WriteLine(potentialMatch);
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `[3f]` matches *either* `3` or `f`.

You just need to get rid of the square brackets:

```
(3f){2,8}
```

Comment: Im not out of the woods yet please could you see my update if you have the time. Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @Dedalous Unfortunately I think what you're asking is too complicated for Regex. You'll have to write your own algorithm in code. Also, is there a reason it must be converted to string? I think this will be easier just left as a byte array.